# How to prevent text in a "display:table-cell" from wrapping?

Tags: html, css

This is what i need [image: This is design and left side (table cell) not wrapping text]

And this is what i get [image: Text wrapping in 2 lines]

This is my HTML

```
                                  <div class="table">
                                    <div class="table-row">
                                        <div class="table-col"><p>Rok važenja:</p></div>
                                        <div class="table-col"><span>Arhitektura</span></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table-row">
                                        <div class="table-col"><p>Zahtevani nivo kvalifikacije:</p></div>
                                        <div class="table-col"><span>Fakultet - VII1 stepen (4-6 godine)</span></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table-row">
                                        <div class="table-col"><p>Radno iskustvo u zanimanju:</p></div>
                                        <div class="table-col"><span>4 godine</span></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table-row">
                                        <div class="table-col"><p>Broj izvršilaca:</p></div>
                                        <div class="table-col"><span>Beograd</span></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table-row">
                                        <div class="table-col"><p>Mesto rada:</p></div>
                                        <div class="table-col"><span>Arhitektura</span></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table-row">
                                        <div class="table-col"><p>Vrsta radnog odnosa/angažovanja:</p></div>
                                        <div class="table-col"><span>Fakultet - VII1 stepen (4-6 godine)</span></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table-row">
                                        <div class="table-col"><p>Napomena: </p></div>
                                        <div class="table-col">
                                            <span>
                                                Svi izrazi, pojmovi, imenice,
                                                pridevi i glagoli u oglasima,
                                                koji su upotrebljeni u muškom rodu,
                                                odnose se bez diskriminacije
                                                i na osobe ženskog pola i obrnuto 
                                                (osim ukoliko specifičnim zahtevima 
                                                posla nije drugačije propisano)
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

And this is my CSS

```
        .table{
            display: table;
            > .table-row{
                display: table-row;
                > .table-col{
                    display: table-cell;
                    vertical-align: top;
                    p{
                        margin-right: 1rem;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I want to stop wrapping text in two lines, how can i achieve this? I never used display: table, this is my first time and i struggle with it. If there is another solution to my problem I would ask you to help me.

Comment: Just the way you prevent anything else from wrapping.

Comment: The code provided is not reproducible. Kindly provide the right code via [Stack snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) or CodePen/JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `nowrap` to force the contents of `<p>` or first column container to display in one line.

```
{
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```